# Употребление наречия "единственно"

Tags: наречия

Не люблю употребления "единственно" в таком, например, контексте:

> Единственно, кто может повлиять на мои решения, это моя семья.

Но возможно, это вкусовщина?

Правим, не правим?.. К автору пристаём?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, семья отвечает на вопрос "что?", и мне больше по душе такой вариант:

**Единственное, что может повлиять на мои решения, это моя семья.**

Я тоже не люблю "единственно что" и "единственно кто", однако Большой толковый словарь дает: **ЕДИНСТВЕННО. I. нареч. к Единственный (1 зн.).Е., что в вас хорошо, это ваш голос** и в Нацкорпуце немало подобных примеров.

*Единственно, кто от нее закипал, это как раз Женя, которому на долю выпало давать девушке задания и потом принимать результаты ее деятельности. [Сергей Эйгенсон. Искусство и жизнь (2003) // Интернет-альманах «Лебедь», 2003.05.26]*

Так что, скорее всего, наша нелюбовь - вкусовщина...